# hide textfield based on date difference in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

How to hide a textfield based on selected date range from extjs date picker? I have to hide the textfield if the difference between start date and end date is more than 30 days.

```
        {
            title: 'Start Date',
            margin: '0 20 0 0',
            items: {
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                itemId: 'startDate',
                showToday: false,
            }
        },
        {
            title: 'End Date',
            margin: '0 20 0 0',
            items: {
                xtype: 'datepicker',
                itemId: 'endDate',
                value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                showToday: false
            }
        }
    ]
},
{
    xtype: 'container',
    layout: 'hbox',
    items: [
        {
            margin: '0 20 0 0',
            items: {
                xtype: 'textfield',
                name: 'text'
            }
        }
```

Comment: please any help i am new to extjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In ExtJs have [Date singletone class](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.Date.html#method-diff) here is method to calculate difference bw 2 dates

I have created an small demo. You can see how it is working [Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2759)

Hope it will help you to solve your problem.

```
Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
    width: 300,
    bodyPadding: 10,
    title: 'Dates',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'Start Date',
        name: 'from_date',
        listeners: {
            select: function () {
                this.up().onDateSelect();
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'datefield',
        anchor: '100%',
        fieldLabel: 'End Date',
        name: 'to_date',
        listeners: {
            select: function () {
                this.up().onDateSelect();
            }
        }
    }, {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Hidable field',
        name: 'fName'
    }],
    onDateSelect: function () {
        var startDate = this.down('[name=from_date]').getValue(),
            endDate = this.down('[name=to_date]').getValue(),
            textField = this.down('[name=fName]');
        textField.setHidden(Ext.Date.diff(startDate, endDate, 'd') > 30);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can listen to `select` event of both datepicker and get & find the difference between both dates and hide the textfield accordingly.

```
    listeners: {
     select: function(datepicker, startDate) {
     var endDate = datepicker.up('form').down('#endDate').getValue();
     var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
     var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
     if (diffDays > 30) {
          datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').hide();
         } else {
          datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').show();
         }
    }
   }
```

Using `handler` :

```
handler: function(datepicker, startDate) {
             var endDate = datepicker.up('form').down('#endDate').getValue();
             var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
             var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
             if (diffDays > 30) {
                  datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').hide();
                 } else {
                  datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').show();
                 }
            }
```

**Sample Working Code:**

```js
Ext.application({
      name: 'Fiddle',

      launch: function() {
        Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
            title: 'Simple Form',
            // The fields
            items: [{
                title: 'Start Date',
                margin: '0 20 0 0',
                items: {
                  xtype: 'datepicker',
                  value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                  itemId: 'startDate',
                  showToday: false,
                  handler: function(datepicker, startDate) {

                       var endDate = datepicker.up('form').down('#endDate').getValue();
                       var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
                       var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
                       if (diffDays > 30) {
                         datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').hide();
                       } else {
                         datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').show();
                       }
                     }
                   
                }
                }, {

                title: 'End Date',
                margin: '0 20 0 0',
                items: {
                  xtype: 'datepicker',
                  itemId: 'endDate',
                  value: Ext.Date.add(new Date(), Ext.Date.DAY, -1),
                  showToday: false,
                  handler: function(datepicker, endDate) {

                       var startDate = datepicker.up('form').down('#startDate').getValue();
                       var oneDay = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000; // hours*minutes*seconds*milliseconds
                       var diffDays = Math.round(Math.abs((endDate.getTime() - startDate.getTime()) / (oneDay)));
                       if (diffDays > 30) {
                         datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').hide();
                       } else {
                         datepicker.up('form').down('[name=text]').show();
                       }
                     }
                   
                },
                },
                {
                  xtype: 'container',
                  layout: 'hbox',
                  items: [{
                    margin: '0 20 0 0',
                    items: {
                      xtype: 'textfield',
                      name: 'text'

                    }
                  }]
                }],
              renderTo: Ext.getBody()
            });
        }
      });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/resources/css/ext-all.css">
<script type="text/javascript"  src="https://cdn.sencha.com/ext/gpl/4.1.1/ext-all-debug.js"></script>
```

Comment: thank you it worked for me but previously i have a handler for my both datepicker how to include those to current listener " handler: function(picker, date) {
                  var timeIntervalPanel = this.up('button#timeIntervalPanel');
                  var endDate = timeIntervalPanel.endDate;
                  timeIntervalPanel.setDates(date, endDate);
                 } "

Comment: I have changed it into handler.Just need to replace listener with handler and remove select property and assign the function directly to handler.

Comment: how to just enable and disable instead of hiding  the fields can you help me out please

Comment: We have `enable()` and `disable()` for that